# Firestore Offline Syncing with large volume of data

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an application which has huge volume (records) of data, roughly 1,00,000+ records. The data is stored in Firestore and overall size is roughly 30~50 MB.

This data mostly remains same for its life time with occasional updates. My application has to provide an offline support where it has to query this data for some management related information. I am planning to use Firestore offline capabilities to keep this data in sync on mobile device and execute queries on this datset.

However, I am not sure if Firestore offline sync feature has the capability to work with large dataset or should I plan to port the downloaded data into any other mobile DB for further caching and processing.

My concerns are:

1. I do not want to download huge amount of data all the time.
2. Some of my queries will return large dataset (10K+). if I run those queries on live data, then probably I end up paying more for something which never change.

Comment: There is no specific documents on limit on the size of the cached data for **Firestore**. Perhaps, there is no limit on the size of the cached data for now since its still in beta but they can put the limit anytime soon. Also, regarding downloading huge amount of data, if you are ready for Firestore offline sync then... Isn't that some what similar to storing the data in local DB?

Comment: @NirajNiroula *firebaser here* While currently the disk cache's size is indeed unbounded, work is under way to allow developers to control the size of the disk storage.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen. Also can you please help me understand, if I keep my connection alive, can I still run query with offline data? My understanding is that once I download all 100K+ records, then only charge I pay is for the data which get updated during syncing. But on the same collection, if I have to run query which returns 10K records, I definitely do not want to run it online and keep my read count charged.

Comment: Document reads that are satisfied from the local cache are not charged. If your local cache contains the most recent data, then most reads will be against the local cache (and thus not charged). There is a great [video about Cloud Firestore pricing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NegFl9p_sE&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=4&t=7s), that explains a lot of details.